# How can I get the git source code used for a TFS 2018 build during one specific TFS 2018 Release environment?

Tags: git, tfs

**Objective**: A TFS (2018) release with an environment that downloads the source code used for the build (using commit hash I would assume) and zips it up before copying it to a file share.

**Current Setup**:
We are using TFS 2018 server (on premises) and I currently have a build process setup that zips up all of the source code and uploads it as an artifact for the build. The repo is over 2gb and this is a long process to both zip it and then to upload it. Additionally, our release that utilizes this build has more than one environment and all of the environments are forced (as far as I can tell) to then download this artifact even though it's not needed for most of them. I would like the build to just do the build and upload the build output as its artifact and only create the zip of the source when deploying to one specific environment. The source code does not need to be the whole git repo, only the source of the commit from which the build was generated.

*Note: All of this is done on a local server with no external connections to the internet though I would not think that will any impact on the solution for this situation.*

Comment: I'd like to take a step back and understand why you're publishing the source code as a build artifact. I can't think of any reason why you'd want to do that.

Comment: That's the point of my question, I DON'T want to publish it as a build artifact. Part of my releases though involve deploying the application to multiple web servers/databases and then once all testing is done, I need to create CDs for release to our client. I created a "release discs" environment in TFS release management and one of the discs to be created is the binary only, the other is the source code. I need to get the source code as part of the release instead of from a build artifact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make Artifacts empty in a release definition, and add tasks in the environment you want to download source code to clone repo, zip it and copy it. Please refer the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I was away for the holidays. I started testing this out and it seems to be hanging on the git commands. I am using the command line 2.* (preview) task (though I'll have to try the 1.x) and I have two commands in the script: "git clone -b $(Build.SourceBranch) --single-branch --progress http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/myproject/_git/myrepo SourceCode" and then "git checkout $(Build.SourceVersion)". The first command creates the "SourceCode" directory with a ".git" dir in it but then just hangs after pulling a few kb. Task manager shows multiple git and git.exe commands.

Comment: Are these two commands working when you run them locally? Did you try my example? Did it work?

Comment: This worked. I should be able to tweak it to get the correct branch/commit. Thanks!